# In my Realtime chat app Chatcontainer component not rendering in real Time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I have a chat app using MERN for which I have followed a youtube video I'm getting an error in which ChatContainer.jsx component not rendering when the user receives a message it will show up after I select a different and then comes back to previous user.

[Screenshot of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiJqM.jpg)

In this you can see the problem on the right it is unable to show the messages in real time.

ChatContainer.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect,useRef } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Logout from './Logout';
import ChatInput from './ChatInput';
import axios from 'axios';
import { sendMessageRoute, getAllMessageRoute } from '../utils/APIRoutes';
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';

function ChatContainer({ currentChat, currentUser, socket}) {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [arrivalMessage, setArrivalMessage] = useState(null);
  const scrollRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
     if (currentChat) {
      const response = await axios.post(getAllMessageRoute, {
       from:currentUser._id,
       to:currentChat._id
      });
      setMessages(response.data);
     }
  }
    fetchData();
  }, [currentUser,currentChat]);

  const handleSendMsg = async(msg) => {
    await axios.post(sendMessageRoute, {
      from: currentUser._id,
      to: currentChat._id,
      message: msg
    });

    socket.current.emit("send-msg", {
      from: currentUser._id,
      to: currentChat._id,
      message:msg
    });

    const msgs = [...messages];
    msgs.push({fromSelf:true, message:msg});
    setMessages(msgs);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket.current) {
      socket.current.on("msg-recieve", (msg) => {
        console.log({msg});
        setArrivalMessage({ fromSelf: false, message: msg });
      });
    }
  }, [socket]);

  useEffect(() => {
    arrivalMessage && setMessages((prev) => [...prev, arrivalMessage]);
  }, [arrivalMessage]);

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }, [messages]);

  return (
    <>
      {currentChat && (
        <Container>
          <div className="chat-header">
            <div className="user-details">
              <div className="avatar">
                <img
                  src={`data:image/svg+xml;base64,${currentChat.avatarImage}`}
                  alt="avatar"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="username">
                <h3>{currentChat.username}</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <Logout />
          </div>
          {/* <Messages /> */}
          <div className="chat-messages">
            {messages.map((message) => {
              return (
                <div ref={scrollRef} key={uuidv4()}>
                  <div
                    className={`message ${
                      message.fromSelf ? "sended" : "recieved"
                    }`}
                  >
                    <div className="content">
                      <p>{message.message}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <ChatInput handleSendMsg={handleSendMsg} />
        </Container>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Chat.jsx

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from "axios";
import { allUsersRoute, host } from '../utils/APIRoutes';
import Contacts from '../components/Contacts';
import Welcome from '../components/Welcome';
import ChatContainer from '../components/ChatContainer';
import {io} from 'socket.io-client';

function Chat() {
  const socket = useRef();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
  const [currentChat, setCurrentChat] = useState(undefined);
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(undefined);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      if (!localStorage.getItem("chat-app-user")){
        navigate("/login");
      }
      else{
        setCurrentUser(await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("chat-app-user")));
        setIsLoaded(true);
      }
  }
    fetchData();
  }, [navigate]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
      socket.current = io(host);
      socket.current.emit("add-user", currentUser._id);
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      if (currentUser){
        if(currentUser.isAvatarImageSet){
          const data = await axios.get(`${allUsersRoute}/${currentUser._id}`);
          setContacts(data.data);
        } else {
          navigate("/setAvatar");
        }
      }
  }
  fetchData();
  }, [currentUser,navigate]);

  const handleChatChange = (chat) => {
    setCurrentChat(chat);
  }
  return (
  <>
  <Container>
    <div className="container">
      <Contacts contacts={contacts} currentUser={currentUser} changeChat={handleChatChange} />
      {
        isLoaded && currentChat === undefined ? (
          <Welcome currentUser={currentUser}/>
        ) : (
          <ChatContainer currentChat={currentChat} currentUser={currentUser} socket={socket}/>
      )}
    </div>
  </Container>
  </>
  )
}
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userRoute = require('./routes/userRoute');
const messageRoute = require('./routes/messagesRoute');
const socket = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,    
}).then(()=>{
    console.log("DB connection successful");
}).catch(err =>{
    console.log(err.message);
})

app.use("/api/auth", userRoute);
app.use("/api/messages", messageRoute);

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
})

const io = socket(server,{
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
        credentials: true,
    },
});

global.onlineUsers = new Map();
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  global.chatSocket = socket;
  socket.on("add-user", (userId) => {
    onlineUsers.set(userId, socket.id);
  });

  socket.on("send-msg", (data) => {
    const sendUserSocket = onlineUsers.get(data.to);
    if (sendUserSocket) {
      socket.to(sendUserSocket).emit("msg-recieve", data.msg);
      
    }
  });
});
```